# How to create Virtual Network for VM's

Tags: linux, networking

I have downloaded a Linux Live CD which I am required to do pentesting using VirtualBox . Live CD is configured for router with Pool Starting Address 192.168.2.2 . Now problem is that my router is't configurable to that setting nor I am allowed to change anything in Live CD. How can i create a virtual network that can be configured as per this requirement ?

Comment: Can you add further virtual ethernet adapters to the VMs?

Comment: @dawud yeah sure

Comment: Are this real requirements or some kind of homework?

Comment: Nope if it were i'd better ask my teachers that rather than here

Comment: You run that live-cd within a vm or is this live-cd providing vbox and vm?

Comment: I can run live cd using virtual box,  its   iso file

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox should allow you to set up a [host-only network](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=34396&start=0) to which you can add an adapter for your LiveCD. The LiveCD should pick up the adapter whose IP address will allow you to connect to other hosts within the host-only network. I'm not sure what you need to pen-test, hopefully it's the host or another guest VM.

It's strange that your LiveCD is *"configured for router with Pool Starting Address 192.168.2.2"*. Most Linux distributions (on LiveCD or not) will work just fine with VirtualBox to access the internet using a VirtualBox NAT adapter. If this answer doesn't meet your needs, it would help to post more information about the specifications of your LiveCD (e.g. what Linux distro is it?) and what you need to pen-test.

Answer (score 0):

If your target is not in VirtualBox, but on your network, you will probably have to configure your network interface for your VM in bridged mode.

If your target is a VM in VirtualBox, you have to configure the target and your pentest VM in host-only network mode.